# joining characters on a string from a list of characters with a certain condition

Tags: python, list, nlp

I'm working on a pronunciation feature to evaluate the quality of the speech from a certain text.

I have a list of the differences between the given text and the speech-to-text like this:

```py
import difflib

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

speech = "chapter 1 it was a bright cold day in April and The clocks were striking 13 Winston Smith his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind slipped quickly through the glass doors of victory Mansions though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him"

groundtruth =  "Chapter 1 It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him."

# Normalization
speech = speech.lower().replace('\n'," ").replace('.',"").replace(',',"").replace('-',"").replace('_',"")
groundtruth = groundtruth.lower().replace('\n'," ").replace('.',"").replace(',',"").replace('-',"").replace('_',"")

speech_diff = [li for li in difflib.ndiff(speech, groundtruth) if li[0] != ' ']

speech_diff
['- 1',
 '- 3',
 '+ t',
 '+ h',
 '+ i',
 '+ r',
 '+ t',
 '+ e',
 '+ e',
 '+ n',
 '- w',
 '- o',
 '- l',
 '- e',
 '-  ',
 '- w',
 '- y',
 '-  ',
 '- s',
 '- m',
 '- e',
 '- t',
 '-  ',
 '- o',
 '- f',
...
 '+  ',
 '+ d',
 '+ u',
 '+ r',
 ...]
```

As you can see, this last list separates the characters from groundtruth and speech. I want to create a data frame to compare the differences between them, like this:

13      -> thirteen
ole wy  -> hallway

¿What alternatives do we have to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet might help.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_diff_dataframe(speech_diff=speech_diff):
  diff_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['speech', 'groundtruth'])
  if speech_diff[-1][0] == '+':
    speech_diff.append('- _')
  elif speech_diff[-1][0] == '-':
    speech_diff.append('+ _')

  speech_diff_words = []
  groundtruth_diff_words = []

  word_diff_speech = ''
  word_diff_groundtruth = ''

  for diff in speech_diff:
    # print(diff)
    if diff[0] == '-':
      word_diff_speech += diff[2]
      if len(word_diff_groundtruth) > 0:
        groundtruth_diff_words.append(word_diff_groundtruth)
        word_diff_groundtruth = ''

    elif diff[0] == '+':
      word_diff_groundtruth += diff[2]
      if len(word_diff_speech) > 0:
        speech_diff_words.append(word_diff_speech)
        word_diff_speech = ''
  
  diff_df['speech'] = speech_diff_words
  diff_df['groundtruth'] = groundtruth_diff_words
  
  return diff_df
```